# Weak Tomato Seedlings 3 weeks in

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, seedlings

I planted tomato seeds into a seed starting tray (one of those 72 pro hex ones) on May 8th and they germinated after only about 4-6 days. They've been growing well under led shop lights and I've been watering daily but recently have started flopping over and being weak. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Is it possible they need to be put into a larger container at this point? The leaves look healthy enough and they've been growing under an led light for 16 hours a day.

Comment: Plus a photo  of the tomato  plants would be very helpful

Comment: MORE LIGHT! Unless it's fungus; then it's time to start over.

Comment: it sounds like transplant shock.

Comment: I suggest gently removing one plant from the cell (cut the cell if you have to - you want to see the roots. My guess is that they're root-bound, but as Bamboo noted, a photo would really help.

Comment: What kind of LED lights are you using (blue and red? "Full spectrum"?) The wrong wavelengths may cause issues with growth.

Comment: I've started transplanting Some of them, I think they just became too large for the container, is now my guess. I shall take photoes of both the one's I've left in and the one's I transplanted this evening when I get home! Hopefully we can solve this mystery

Comment: tomato's produce 100ds of seeds in every fruit and in every pack, best to plant at least 20 and keep the best ones when they have enough leaves to tell which are strongest.

Comment: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/46021/25662 

Photos of my tomat plants in this new question thread